# Trying to write a custom library for a blinking light

Tags: arduino, libraries

I'm new to arduino and want to make some libraries. Full Disclosure: I am not a programmer and have been following some tutorials and reading as much as I can about rewriting functions as libraries. Yet, I still have some questions.

**Example**: I want to set up a custom blink pattern for the LEDpin on my arduino UNO. I want to include this blinking code on future projects and would like to use it with the #include statement when I start a new project. (easy?)

As an example:

The often referenced Morse Code Library tutorial [here](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial)

I have the files saved in ..\My Documents\Arduino\libraries\Morse\morse\
there are 4 files:

```
keywords.txt
morse.c
morse.h
morse.ino
```

They exist in those files exactly as the final code examples on the linked page.

> Question 1: can anyone verify if this tutorial is accurate for an
>   Arduino Uno using 1.6.4?

I can not get this or any "library" that I "create from scratch" to compile or upload to the mcu.

It doesn't seem to get any simpler than this in terms of a "custom library" tutorial. Would it help to post the error codes or PEBCAK?

Much of the [style guide stuff](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5:-Library-specification) was too advanced for me to follow but I did try to put the .c and .h files into a sub directory called \src. It didn't help.

I can't get rid of the ..\Morse\morse double directory. I am doing everything in arduino IDE and it makes it's own folders. If I move files around after I save it, it doesn't work when I reopen it and automatically resaves it where it was and I end up with all these weird duplicate files and folders.

> Question 2: Do I need to be working in some other editor when creating a library?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you followed this tutorial? [link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial) Particularly the part which states "First, make a Morse directory inside of the libraries sub-directory of your sketchbook directory. Copy or move the Morse.h and Morse.cpp files into that directory. Now launch the Arduino environment. If you open the Sketch > Import Library menu, you should see Morse inside. The library will be compiled with sketches that use it."

Comment: That is the tutorial I was trying to follow, yes. ^^

I tried this a couple of times and it never worked quite right. Thanks for pointing it out again. I deleted everything and started over from scratch (again) and got it to work. 

Thank you! Now I get to see if my code works (read: I'll be back). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file in your folder should be:

```
Librairies/
  Morse/
    morse.cpp
    morse.h
    keywords.txt
```